# How to use mathjax in placeholder of textbox in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, mathjax, asp.net-placeholder

I recently added `MathJax` to my webform, I'm able to do everything except figure out how to use `MathJax` as a placeholder inside a `TextBox`.

example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" placeholder="$x^2$"></asp:TextBox>
```

My placeholder doesn't want to use `MathJax` even though everywhere else it's fine.
Is there a specific way to do this when using `MathJax` inside the placeholder attribute?

Here is my `MathJax` configuration:

```
<head>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom attributes in server side with `Attributes` property and the `Add()` method.

In the `Page_Load` event:

```
textbox1.Attributes.Add("placeholder","$x^2$");
```

When your page is rendered you should have in the HTML result:

```html
<input id="textbox1" type="text" placeholder="$x^2$" />
```

Don't forget to add the `runat="server"` in your ASP.NET control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox1" runat="server" placeholder="$x^2$"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Ok I was able to do it but it still doesnt show the MathJax form. It just shows as: $x^2$. Do you know why its not converting it to MathJax?

Comment: any idea what's wrong? It looks like the placeholder is not loading the mathjax.

Comment: I have been researching and I have concluded that **MathJax** does not work with input elements. You can see in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/nugjqqhk/.

Comment: there is no way around this at all? No alternative solution?